# How to set a minimum width to a webpage in twitter bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Would it be possible to set a minimum width on a responsive layout where it would not re-size the webpage beyond that specified point. For example set the width to be 468 px Min and add scroll bars to any devise/browser which has any width less than that ?

- My site breaks up in mobile phones after a certain width , almost impossible to replicate the same site on desktop when it becomes too small .

Comment: investigate into css media queries

Answer (score 0):

Add your own CSS file with the following:

```
.container-fluid
{
    min-width: 468px !important;
}
```

Place it to load after the bootstrap CSS files.

[Bootstrap 2.3.2 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)

Comment: err ? thats just setting the min width for a specific element, what happens with my site is even if i set the min width to something like 768 px ,once its on a smaller devise it sill inherits those fluid layout propeerties and causes some of the elements to flow down instead of side by side.. when it clearly has the space to go side by side...

Comment: Sorry my bad. Fluid elements should be nested in row-fluid and container-fluid elements in bootstrap 2.3.2. So if you set container-fluid min-width, you will limit the fluid behavior. Check the link I have added to original post.